# C# MVC - User is duplicated when calling Reply

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

I'm trying to make a simple forum using MVC and I can't figure out why the user that is posting the reply is getting duplicated.

Here is the Reply Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Reply(string Title, string Content,int ReplyTo)
    {
        Post masterPost = db.Posts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PostID == ReplyTo);
        Post post = new Post();
        post.PostID = 0;
        post.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        post.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
        post.ReplyTo = masterPost;
        post.Forum = db.Forums.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.ForumID == masterPost.Forum.ForumID);
        post.User = (User)Session["User"];
        post.Title = Title;
        post.Content = Content;

        //if (ModelState.IsValid)
        //{
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("View", "Posts", new { id = ReplyTo });
        //}
        return View(post);
    }
```

This is the Post entity:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual Forum Forum { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Post ReplyTo { get; set; }
}
```

This is the User entity:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisteredOn { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever the ReplyTo action is called it creates the Post but it also duplicates the User that is stored in the session (with a different UserID).

Also, I commented the *ModelState.IsValid* because for some reason it always returned as false although the entity is fully filled and there are no DataAnnotations that can cause it to be invalid.

**Edit**
This is the error of the ModelState:
*{"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Models.Post' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}*

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Before you save the post, what is the value in post.User.UserID? I'm willing to bet that it's 0.

Comment: The posted code is braking MVC pattern by not validating your posted model. Your model is invalid because, in the posted `Post postParam` you have missing required fields or `NULL` values for properties that do expect some value.

Comment: I changed my Reply function and it still duplicates the User entity.

Also, the UserID is not 0 and it has the full user details.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you why the ModelState is invalid.  You don't have to have DataAnnotations to make a property required. As you can't set the primitives to null, they also count as "Required" properties and ModelState becomes invalid if none is provided.

In the above example, I think you are not posting the CreatedOn or PostId properties (or both). As you are only posting two properties that are of value to you(Title and Content), you will be better off creating a simple view model that just contained those two properties. If you don't want to do that, even accepting two named parameters would be better.

The following is an example that uses the view model. Please note that you can add the ReplyTo property to the view model.

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public int ReplyTo {get; set;}
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
 }
```

and you can use it like so:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Reply(PostViewModel viewModel)
    {
        Post masterPost = db.Posts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PostID == viewModel.ReplyTo);
        Post post = new Post();
        post.PostID = 0;
        post.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        post.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
        post.ReplyTo = masterPost;
        post.Forum = db.Forums.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.ForumID == masterPost.Forum.ForumID);
        post.User = (User)Session["User"];
        post.Title = viewModel.Title;
        post.Content = viewModel.Content;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("View", "Posts", new { id = ReplyTo });
        }
        return View(post);
    }
```

As for the user being duplicated, I think the reason for that is the lack of Key attribute in the User class.

Comment: I tried adding the Key attribute to each of my entities and it didn't help and the user kept getting duplicated.